# Static struct declaration and initialization in c header file

Tags: c, struct, embedded, header-files, microcontroller

I develop an embedded application which uses the MindTree Bluetooth SDK.

I have the following in a header file:

```
typedef struct {
    UCHAR outputDir;
    UCHAR reset;
    UCHAR nack;
    UCHAR startCondition;
    UCHAR stopCondition;
    UCHAR busy;
} USCI_ConfigurationFlags;

static USCI_ConfigurationFlags usciConfigFlags = { UCTR, UCSWRST, UCNACKIFG, UCTXSTT, UCTXSTP, UCBBUSY };
```

Later in two .c files I include the above header and use the **usciConfigFlags** on different occasions sometimes from within an interrupt.

Is this legal?

I'm trying to understand why(and if it is related to the question) the values of the struct change at runtime, after calling the BT_bluetooth_on method in the SDK.

Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`static` here doesn't mean what you think it means. It means that the declaration and variable will only be visible in one compilation unit. That is, you have two independent instances of `usciConfigFlags`.

If you want a global variable, you need to use `extern` not `static` and make the actual declaration (without `extern`) with the initial value in one of your c files.

Also be weary of changing the values in the struct without proper locking. Read-only concurrent access is usually fine.

Comment: Yes, and I tend to consider initializing global values in a .h header file a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem you include the header in two `.c` file. The `static` modifier limits the accessible scope of the variable in the file including the header only. The two `usciConfigFlags` in two different files are not identical.

Also `static` does not mean constant. So you can modify the value of the structure in whatever way you want.

The following is from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)

> In computer programming, a static variable is a variable that has been
>   allocated statically — whose lifetime extends across the entire run of
>   the program. This is in contrast to the more ephemeral automatic
>   variables (local variables), whose storage is allocated and
>   deallocated on the call stack; and in contrast to objects whose
>   storage is dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Prepending a static keyword to a variable makes it visible only in the current translation unit (i.e. if within a function, only that function and if within a file, only that file).

It is never a good idea to define a variable in a header file. Even if you need two static variables in two different files with the same name, it is better that you put in the .c file itself as it helps in better maintaince and readability as you will be clear in which all files it is actually present and is being used.

If you add it in a header file, then at a later point, if some other .c file includes this header, then unneccessarily this variable will included for that translation unit.

Epsalon had suggested other good points which you can consider.